# How to parse a deep URL using jQuery params()?

Tags: java, android, jquery, json, url

Building an Android app that needs to parse a URL built with deep parameters using jQuery `params()`.

Sample URL:

```
http://webapp.example.com/#params%5Bid%5D=33330&type=detail&channel=ss&view=Detail
```

The result should be JSON, which I can feed into Gson.  Manual parsing is not optimal; a generic solution is preferable.

How can this task be done?

Answer (score 0):

at first glance I thought you need a js/jquery solution. But on closer inspection, probably java. Anywhoo, I had already dont the former so you get both!

Js/jquery

```
url="http://webapp.example.com/#params%5Bid%5D=33330&type=detail&channel=ss&view=Detail";

delimatedString = url.substring(url.indexOf("#")+1,url.length); //remove everything before the #

var jsonObject = new Object();

$.each(delimatedString.split("&"), function(index, item) {//for loop to spit at the *&
   //item is now in the syntax key=value 
   var keyValPair = item.split("="); //split each item at the = to seperate
   var key = keyValPair[0];
   var value = keyValPair[1];

   jsonObject[key]=value;
});
```

java

```
String delimatedStrings = url.substring("&"+1, url.length)
String[] keyValuePairs = delimatedString.split("&");  
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();  
for (String keyValuePair : keyValuePairs)  
   {  
      String key = delimatedString.split("=")[0];  
      String value = delimatedString.split("=")[1];  
      map.put(key, value);  
    }
```

ps. I didnt compile the java, and you will need an external lib to take care of the map to JSON conversion.